# French translation: How to make text in <a> tag display fully

Tags: html, css

[image]

Guys take a look at the attached image. "Reset Password" translates to "reinitialisez votre mote de passe" in French. So the text in the `<a>` tag isn't displaying fully in iPhone. `<a>` tag's width is set to 100% for iPhone. When clicked on `<a>` link, a small form gets opened within that `<div>` itself. I tried `word-wrap: break-word` too. Doesn't work.

Comment: can u show your html css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try adding `white-space: "normal";` to your `a` tag? Like this:

```
<a style="white-space: normal !important;">Reset Password</a>
```

Or in your css:

```
a {
    white-space: normal !important;
}
```